# Should i Use Docker to Deploy a Web API Project (Microservices) to Azure Web App

Tags: c#, .net, azure, asp.net-web-api

I have several Microservices (not .net core) built using normal Web API.I need to deploy it to Web API on Azure.Docket support was not added by default ? Should i containerize the projects before deploying to Individual Azure Web Apps?

Comment: did the answer help?

Comment: @Sajeetharan Yes.. i guess lots of work will be needed to convert an existing web api project to Azure Function.

Comment: hmm then better to deploy as it is to app service if you are not worried about the cost. mark if the answer helped

Comment: @Sajeetharan Does functions save lot of cost ?

Comment: it depends on your micro service design and the number of services.

Answer (score 1):

It's not mandatory to containerize your APIs if you really do not want to deploy using containers. You can directly build the code and publish to Azure App Service (WebApp) either directly from Visual Studio/Visual Studio Code or Azure Devops with ARM templates.

If you want to loon into other options of deployment, have a look at [Choose an Azure compute service for your application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/technology-choices/compute-decision-tree)

Comment: Should i check serverless ? Is lot of work required for converting the existing project to serverless?

Comment: if you are looking to refactor/rearchitect code serverless with Azure functions could be one option, if the microservices can be easily converted that would be the best option

Comment: I think that it would not be possible to refactor the code ... I guess separate web apps should be used for each microservice.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/technology-choices/compute-decision-tree

Answer (score -1):

its not necessary , before you jumped into containerize platform check do you really need this or not. if you are really want to host it in cloud please find something similar like  (AWS LAMBDA ) in Azure which is server less  . that may help you. #

Comment: The project is already created .. i guess lots of changes will be required for serverless.

Comment: AWS lambda in azure? lol

Comment: @ Sajeetharan i mean similar functionalities in Azure ....

Comment: ok got it! i was kidding though :)